# Catch is returning a custom error page and not the error message

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I am calling a controller with Ajax Post, In the controller, catch is returning a custom error page, instead of returning the error message.

**Catch Controller:**

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return BadRequest(ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException?.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

**Post Ajax:**

```
$.post({
    url: eapi + 'pedido/' + id_empresa + '/' + token_emp + '/' + agendamentotf,
    data: JSON.stringify(vm.ped_post),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var response = data;
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error.responseText);
    }
});
```

This error.responseText is returning an error page and not the error message.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert in jquery's post, but i've found that you dont enter the error function where you do, but this way:

```
$.post({
    url: eapi + 'pedido/' + id_empresa + '/' + token_emp + '/' + agendamentotf,
    data: JSON.stringify(vm.ped_post),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var response = data;
    }
    
})
.fail((xhr, status, error) => {
        console.log(error.responseText);
    });
```

you can see it [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are trying to use $.post instead of $.ajax
Here is your corrected code:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: eapi + 'pedido/' + id_empresa + '/' + token_emp + '/' + agendamentotf,
     data: JSON.stringify(vm.ped_post),
     headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },
     success: function(data) {
         var response = data;
     },
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
         console.log(error);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your controller isn't configured as an API controller, in which case you might need to change your action return type to JsonResult.

Answer (score 0):

Try use a simple string in the BadRequest, like `return BadRequest("Test");`

I suspect this code may throw another exception.

```
ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException?.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace
```